# Show monthly installment prices on WooCommerce single product page with a treshold

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I have been having troubles implementing this on our WordPress/WooCommerce system.

We devised a method where users can see monthly installment prices on the product page.

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'price_per_month', 5 );

function  price_per_month() {

    global $product;
    $price = $product->get_regular_price();
    $months1 = 3;
    $months2 = 6;
    $months3 = 12;
    $months4 = 24;

    $price_per_month1 = ($price / $months1);
    $price_per_month2 = ($price / $months2);
    $price_per_month3 = ($price / $months3);
    $price_per_month4 = ($price / $months4);
 
    echo "
    <div id='ppm-container'>
        <div id='ppm-text'>
            <b>Insert Title</b></br>
            Pay from only:</br>
            <b>PHP ". round($price/3,2,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP) ."</b> for 3 months</br>
            <b>PHP ". round($price/6,2,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP) ."</b> for 6 months</br>
            <b>PHP ". round($price/12,2,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP) ."</b> for 12 months</br>
            <b>PHP ". round($price/24,2,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP) ."</b> for 24 months</br>
            Insert Footer.</br>
        </div>
    </div>
    ";
     
}
```

What we wanted for the code is **not to run if the original price is below, say, 3000**. What code should I use for this? I tried a basic if/else program but that did not work.

I'd also love feedback on this code as well. We were looking for something similar [to this one](https://github.com/andersonfranco/woocommerce-installments), but that was the only available plugin we saw. The tables automatically computed for every month on a specified range and so I decided to code it on my own.

Comment: A link to the implementation would be nice to see how this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using multiple `if/else` conditions you can use an [`array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and a [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop.

For the threshold you can add a simple `if` condition

So you get:

```php
function price_per_month() {
    global $product;
    
    // Is a WC product 
    if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
        
        // Only for 'simple' products
        if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {          
            // Set months
            $months = array ( 3, 6, 12, 24 );
            
            // Treshold
            $treshold = 3000;
            
            // Get price
            $price = $product->get_regular_price();
            
            // Price greather than or equal to treshold
            if ( $price >= $treshold ) {        
                echo '<div id="ppm-container"><div id="ppm-text">';
                echo '<h2>Insert title</h2>';
                echo '<p>Pay from only:</p>';
                
                // Iterate over array
                foreach ( $months as $month ) {
                    echo '<p>PHP ' . round( $price / $month, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP ) . ' for ' . $month .  ' months</p>';
                }
                
                echo '<p>Insert Footer</p>';
                echo '</div></div>';
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'price_per_month', 5 );
```